# Simperium login screen cancel/edit

Tags: simperium

I am using the Simperium data sync framework and it is working great.  However I am trying to edit the login screen that it comes with to add a Cancel button on it that will just close the window.  I see the .xib file that I could add the button to, but I don't think we have access to the code behind it.  How can I add a cancel button to that screen?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no good way to do this. In the short-term we'll add an option to make the interface cancellable since that's a common use case. And thereafter we'll make it possible to subclass the authentication class for cases where you'd like to implement custom behavior.